# NSLocalizedString with a Double and a specifier

Tags: xcode, swiftui, double, nslocalizedstring, specifier

I tried a lot of possibilities to specify only "2 digits" after the "." for this `Double` without success.

I don't know where to add `, specifier: "%.2f"`.

```
// ContentView.swift
Text(String(format: NSLocalizedString("text [%lf]", comment: "Item"), item.value))

// Localizable.strings
"text [%lf]" = "Item [%lf]";
```

Do you have an idea where/how to add it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm so dumb! I just had to replace `[%lf]` by `[%.2f]` directly in the `NSLocalizedString`.

```
// ContentView.swift
Text(String(format: NSLocalizedString("text [%.2f]", comment: "Item"), item.value))

// Localizable.strings
"text [%.2f]" = "Item [%.2f]";
```

Comment: Your solution is good. Just want to add that only the localized string needs to have the %.2lf ("Item [%.2f]") as this is this string that will be used .